# Frequent Pattern growth in R or Python

Tags: python, r

Apriori algorithm is old and slow. Frequent pattern trees are much faster. However, I can't find frequent pattern tree libraries neither in R or in Python.
I'm sure they exists somewhere.
I'm not talking about home made code that can be found on the internet somewhere.
Does anyone know any Frequent Pattern Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FP-Growth is one algorithm which extracts frequent itemsets based on trees. For R please take a look here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Frequent_Pattern_Mining/The_FP-Growth_Algorithm. Same with Python. Just google FP-Growth and Python and pick a library which seems professional enough for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link and see if it provides what you need:

[PyFIM - Frequent Item Set Mining for Python](http://www.borgelt.net/pyfim.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [pyfpgrowth](https://pypi.org/project/pyfpgrowth/).
This is a  Python implementation of the Frequent Pattern Growth algorithm.
you can find the documentation here
[Documentation](http://Documentation:%20https://fp-growth.readthedocs.org.)